# Compositing frames using the mean in opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to create a composite image using the mean of two images by looping over a set of frames from a video and getting the mean of composite + next frame.

However it comes out looking terrible. What am I doing wrong? I think I must be misunderstanding the way that arrays are added/divided in numpy or opencv. Since it comes out half as bright as it should be, as if the addition never happened. Plus the harsh edges of the trees.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frames = [cv2.imread('./frames2/thumb0001.jpg'),
          cv2.imread('./frames2/thumb0002.jpg')]

composite = np.zeros((500, 500), dtype=np.uint8)
composite
for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(gray, (500, 500))
    composite = (resized_frame + composite) / 2
    composite = composite.astype(np.uint8)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('frame', composite)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I was using an array of type `np.uint8` which would overflow when doing the addition. All I needed to do was to change this to be `np.uint32` so it could hold that number before dividing again.

I also needed to ensure that on the first frame I didn't add 0 + frame, the first frame should make composite = frame.

```
    if i == 0:
        composite = resized_frame
    else:
        composite = composite.astype(np.uint32)
        composite = (resized_frame + composite) / 2
        composite = composite.astype(np.uint8)
```

[image]